# Fantasy novel about a girl pretending to be a noble. She has extremely high luck

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book at a library a while ago. I didn't read the whole thing, just the first few chapters.

There was a plantation with slaves. At night, the plantation would always be covered in fog. One day, a man came to visit the owner, and met with the slaves. The next chapter was about a slum girl who was pretending to be a noble. I think she had extremely high luck.

This is all I remember about it, but if anyone could figure out the title, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What's the fantasy element to this story?

Comment: The "man" had magic, and many other characters that it's not clear if the OP encountered or not yet. The night fog was widely believed to be magic as well at this point in the story.

Answer (score 29):

Could this be [*The Final Empire*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/68428.The_Final_Empire) by Brandon Sanderson?

> Vin is a part of a crime group who is seeking to swindle some money.
> She has made it her life’s goal to be as meek as possible, having
> endured abuse from both crime and her brother who betrayed her. She
> has a unique hidden skill she calls luck that places people in favour
> of her boss Camon, but this skill is discovered and explained by
> Kelsier.

[image] [image]  [image]

The plantations are notably misty and the locals are afeared of it.

> The skaa hovels loomed in the waning light. Already, Kelsier could see the mists beginning to form, clouding the air, and giving the moundlike buildings a surreal, intangible look. The hovels stood unguarded; there was no need for watchers, for no skaa would venture outside once night arrived. Their fear of the mists was far too strong.

Comment: A better quote for the misty plantations would be from the first chapter of Final Empire. Matches the question's description almost exactly. The paragraph you're quoting is Dockson talking, not Vin.

Comment: @fez - Feel free to swap it out.

Comment: The opening chapters is about Kelsier spending a day at a slave plantation, and using his magic against the slave owners.  And their whole world is covered in (supposedly) dangerous magic fog at nights.

Comment: Additionally, Vin refers to her abilities "Luck" before they are explained to her.